# Microsoft Azure DevOps SQL Query shows history? How to show active requests only

Tags: sql, tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to make a Query that returns any request in TFS that has `Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem.CDS_Project_HotFixRelated` like 1. As you can see in the code below it returns the Request and Project name.

```
SELECT DISTINCT  system_title          AS Request,
                
                TP.ProjectNodeName    AS Project_Name

  FROM Tfs_Warehouse.dbo    .DimTeamProject TP
  INNER JOIN Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem wi
  ON TP.ProjectNodeSK = wi.TeamProjectSK

        
WHERE
wi.CDS_Project_HotFixRelated LIKE '1' 
AND System_state  != 'Closed'
AND wi.System_IsDeleted  = '0'
AND wi.System_WorkItemType  LIKE 'Request'
Order by wi.System_Title DESC
```

When I run this, it returns every instance of a request that has been recorded from history.
E.g. I have this Project and request that get returned but in actuality, the project now has been closed.
The span of this project went from Proposed to Active to Closed but due to `DISTINCT`, it will only show one of the nonclosed instances.
So this returns the records of the previous states.

What should I do differently to only return the active projects instead of including the history?

Apologies if any technical terms are worded weirdly, I am a new user to Azure-DevOps and TFS

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are looking for the [Current Work Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/report/sql-reports/table-reference-current-work-items?view=azure-devops-2020) table?

> You can query for data about the current state of bugs, tasks, and
> other types of work items by using the FactCurrentWorkItem table and
> the associated dimension tables.

Comment: I tried using that using same `WHERE` and using 

`From Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.FactCurrentWorkItem FCWI
inner JOIN  TFS_Warehouse.dbo.DimTeamProject DTP
on FCWI.CurrentWorkItemBK = DTP.ProjectNodeName
inner Join Tfs_Warehouse.dbo.DimWorkItem wi
ON  FCWI.CurrentWorkItemBK = wi.System_Title` 

and it shows no results when I know there should be at least 2 results

Comment: using FactCurrentWorkItem in DevOps2020 still shows history